# IOS Parse Anypic not saving images correctly

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform, objective-c-blocks

I am trying to use the AnyPic sample parse app code to create something similar to instagram. Instead of using AnyPics built in UIImagePickerController, I chose to use AVFoundation classes to get a more custom feel. At this point I am simply trying to save my images, here are the functions where it all happens:

First the view controller is initialized with an image:

```
- (id)initWithImage:(UIImage *)aImage {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    if (self) {
        if (!aImage) {
            return nil;
        }

        self.image = aImage;
        self.fileUploadBackgroundTaskId = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
        self.photoPostBackgroundTaskId = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    }
    return self;
}
```

In view did load shouldUpload is called:

```
[self shouldUploadImage:self.image];
```

The shouldUpload looks like this:

```
- (BOOL)shouldUploadImage:(UIImage *)anImage {
    NSLog(@"FTEditPhotoViewController::shouldUploadImage %@",anImage);
    UIImage *resizedImage = [anImage resizedImageWithContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit bounds:CGSizeMake(560.0f, 560.0f) interpolationQuality:kCGInterpolationHigh];
    UIImage *thumbnailImage = [anImage thumbnailImage:86.0f transparentBorder:0.0f cornerRadius:10.0f interpolationQuality:kCGInterpolationDefault];

    NSLog(@"shouldUploadImage::resizedImage: %@",resizedImage);
    NSLog(@"shouldUploadImage::thumbnailImage: %@",thumbnailImage);

    // JPEG to decrease file size and enable faster uploads & downloads
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(resizedImage, 0.8f);
    NSData *thumbnailImageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(thumbnailImage);

    //NSLog(@"shouldUploadImage::imageData: %@",imageData);
    //NSLog(@"shouldUploadImage::thumbnailImageData: %@",thumbnailImageData);

    if (!imageData || !thumbnailImageData) {
        return NO;
    }

    self.photoFile = [PFFile fileWithData:imageData];
    self.thumbnailFile = [PFFile fileWithData:thumbnailImageData];

    NSLog(@"shouldUploadImage::photoFile: %@",self.photoFile);
    NSLog(@"shouldUploadImage::thumbnailFile: %@",self.thumbnailFile);

    // Request a background execution task to allow us to finish uploading the photo even if the app is backgrounded
    self.fileUploadBackgroundTaskId = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:self.fileUploadBackgroundTaskId];
    }];

    [self.photoFile saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        if (succeeded) {
            [self.thumbnailFile saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
                [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:self.fileUploadBackgroundTaskId];

                if (error) {
                    NSLog(@"self.thumbnailFile saveInBackgroundWithBlock: %@", error);
                }
            }];
        } else {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:self.fileUploadBackgroundTaskId];
        }

        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"self.photoFile saveInBackgroundWithBlock: %@", error);
        }
    }];

    return YES;
}
```

And finally when the user clicks send/publish the functionality is handled in the following code:

```
- (void)doneButtonAction:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"FTEditPhotoViewController::doneButtonAction");
    NSDictionary *userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionary];
    NSString *trimmedComment = [self.commentTextField.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
    if (trimmedComment.length != 0) {
        userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                    trimmedComment,kFTEditPhotoViewControllerUserInfoCommentKey,
                    nil];
    }

    // Make sure there were no errors creating the image files
    if (!self.photoFile || !self.thumbnailFile) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Couldn't post your photo" message:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Dismiss", nil];
        [alert show];
        return;
    }

    // both files have finished uploading

    NSLog(@"doneButtonAction::self.photoFile: %@",self.photoFile);
    NSLog(@"doneButtonAction::self.thumbnailFile: %@",self.thumbnailFile);

    // create a photo object
    PFObject *photo = [PFObject objectWithClassName:kFTPhotoClassKey];
    [photo setObject:[PFUser currentUser] forKey:kFTPhotoUserKey];
    [photo setObject:self.photoFile forKey:kFTPhotoPictureKey];
    [photo setObject:self.thumbnailFile forKey:kFTPhotoThumbnailKey];

    NSLog(@"doneButtonAction::PFObject photo: %@",photo);

    // photos are public, but may only be modified by the user who uploaded them
    PFACL *photoACL = [PFACL ACLWithUser:[PFUser currentUser]];
    [photoACL setPublicReadAccess:YES];
    photo.ACL = photoACL;

    NSLog(@"doneButtonAction::PFObject photoACL: %@",photoACL);

    // Request a background execution task to allow us to finish uploading the photo even if the app is backgrounded
    self.photoPostBackgroundTaskId = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:self.photoPostBackgroundTaskId];
        NSLog(@"FTEditPhotoViewController::doneButtonAction::saveInBackgroundWithBlock - photoPostBackgroundTaskId");
    }];

    // Save the Photo PFObject
    [photo saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        if (succeeded) {

            NSLog(@"FTEditPhotoViewController::doneButtonAction::saveInBackgroundWithBlock - succeeded");

            [[FTCache sharedCache] setAttributesForPhoto:photo likers:[NSArray array] commenters:[NSArray array] likedByCurrentUser:NO];

            // userInfo might contain any caption which might have been posted by the uploader
            if (userInfo) {
                NSString *commentText = [userInfo objectForKey:kFTEditPhotoViewControllerUserInfoCommentKey];

                if (commentText && commentText.length != 0) {
                    // create and save photo caption
                    PFObject *comment = [PFObject objectWithClassName:kFTActivityClassKey];
                    [comment setObject:kFTActivityTypeComment forKey:kFTActivityTypeKey];
                    [comment setObject:photo forKey:kFTActivityPhotoKey];
                    [comment setObject:[PFUser currentUser] forKey:kFTActivityFromUserKey];
                    [comment setObject:[PFUser currentUser] forKey:kFTActivityToUserKey];
                    [comment setObject:commentText forKey:kFTActivityContentKey];

                    PFACL *ACL = [PFACL ACLWithUser:[PFUser currentUser]];
                    [ACL setPublicReadAccess:YES];
                    comment.ACL = ACL;

                    [comment saveEventually];
                    [[FTCache sharedCache] incrementCommentCountForPhoto:photo];
                }
            } else {
                [photo saveEventually];
            }

            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:FTTabBarControllerDidFinishEditingPhotoNotification object:photo];
        } else {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Couldn't post your photo" message:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Dismiss", nil];
            [alert show];
        }
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:self.photoPostBackgroundTaskId];
    }];

    // Dismiss this screen
    [self.parentViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

I have traced the photo and thumbnail and they do seem to be there but just aren't being saved to parse.

```
[5934:60b] FTEditPhotoViewController::shouldUploadImage <UIImage: 0x14d3bbf0>
[5934:60b] shouldUploadImage::resizedImage: <UIImage: 0x14db07e0>
[5934:60b] shouldUploadImage::thumbnailImage: <UIImage: 0x14db0c80>
[5934:60b] shouldUploadImage::photoFile: <PFFile: 0x14eb99d0>
[5934:60b] shouldUploadImage::thumbnailFile: <PFFile: 0x14db17d0>
[5934:60b] FTEditPhotoViewController::doneButtonAction
[5934:60b] doneButtonAction::self.photoFile: <PFFile: 0x14eb99d0>
[5934:60b] doneButtonAction::self.thumbnailFile: <PFFile: 0x14db17d0>
[5934:60b] doneButtonAction::PFObject photo: <Photo:new:(null)> {
    ACL = "<PFACL: 0x14db43e0>";
    image = "<PFFile: 0x14eb99d0>";
    thumbnail = "<PFFile: 0x14db17d0>";
    user = "<PFUser:WDk0diNx8m>";
}
[5934:60b] doneButtonAction::PFObject photoACL: <PFACL: 0x14da8180>
[5934:60b] FTEditPhotoViewController::doneButtonAction::saveInBackgroundWithBlock - succeeded
```

When I look at my class in parse all I see is the word file with no image. Can anyone help me figure out why the images are not being saved to parse?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try logging the url for the files: `NSLog(@"self.photoFile: %@", self.photoFile.url);` to see if the save has finished, simply checking `if (!self.photoFile || !self.thumbnailFile)` isn't enough since they have a value but may not be finished saving. You can't add unsaved files to an object.

Comment: Thank you for that it helped me out. This is a bit weird but it looks like the files are being saved on parse, but instead of viewing the image online after I click  on it, the image is being downloaded onto my desktop. I am going to experiment with this more and figure out why they are not being saved as jpgs. thanks!

Comment: If the name doesn't end in jpg then you will need to manually set the MIME type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Timothys suggestions to print out the URL, I realized that the URL did not have a file extension. I then noticed that whenever I clicked the file entry in parse, the file was being downloaded to my desktop and the image was being saved on parse. However, it was not saved as a JPEG, or a PNG for the thumbnail as I had intended. The URL ended in "-file" which was a link to download the file stored in parse. I fixed my problem by using the following code:

```
self.photoFile = [PFFile fileWithName:@"photo.jpeg" data:imageData];
self.self.thumbnailFile = [PFFile fileWithName:@"thumbnail.png" data:imageData];
```

This saves the image as a jpeg or a thumbnail respectively.